# Add a label above UITextField from custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create a custom TextField class in which I can add label(like the one below) from an IBInspectable property in storyboard.

**Focused State**

[image]

**Default State**

[image]

I was able to achieve the focused and not focused state of the TextField in the custom class but unable to figure out how to place the UILabel above the TextField from the custom class.

Here is what I have tried so far

```swift
@IBDesignable class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupTextField()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: coder)
        setupTextField()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setupTextField()
    }

    private func setupTextField() {
        applyDefaultStyle()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyActiveStyles), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyDefaultStyles), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "First name"
        addSubview(label)
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

But the label is not visible.

Comment: I don't see, where you gave position for your label? And btw if you want to create similar design, you better go with custom view, with label and textField inside

Comment: You gave a bottom constraint for your label, but you also need a leading constraint (at least). Also the bottom constraint's constant should be -10 instead of 10 (OR you could swap the order of the anchors, like `topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)`).

Comment: @vpoltave I am also confused about how to position the label, so I added a constraint in the last line of the setupTextField function to see where the label goes. So it's not possible without a custom view then?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler I updated the constraints as you said, but still, the label is not visible.

Comment: Looks like I am unable to place the label outside the border of the TextField.

Comment: Try subclassing `UIView` instead of `UITextField`, then add a label and text field inside of your view subclass, and set up the constraints as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constraints to label left and vertically centre and don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

```
 private func setupTextField() {
      applyDefaultStyle()
      addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyActiveStyles), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
      addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyDefaultStyles), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)

      let label = UILabel()
      label.text = "First name"
      addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your method is making the label go inside the TextField (https://share.getcloudapp.com/OAubnJqG). I want it above the TextField, like in the screenshot in question.

Comment: I think I am unable to place the label outside the border of the TextField.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: with minimal efforts you can achieve this :)